Keyboard randomly stops working properly
During the last few weeks, when I'm using my computer, suddenly, out of nowhere, my keyboard starts acting weird. It acts as if I was pressing the Ctrl key constantly when I'm actually not pressing it (when I click "s" into a software, instead of typing the letter out, it saves the file, when I tipe "g" into google, it doesn't actually type the letter into the search engine but instead pops up my browser's "search" window). I have a desktop PC and have tried disconnecting and reconnecting the keyboard again, but it doesn't do anything. It seems to be a software issue.
It is extremely annoying and the only thing that stops it is to restart the computer. I swear, I've had to restart it 5 times in the last hour alone, but after a while, the problem returns. What is happening? Any help is appreciated.
Edit: it is a wired keyboard, and for some reason it mainly stops working when using the music engraving software MuseScore (not sure if this has anything to do with it). It's an old genius comfy kb.

Is this an external wired or wireless keyboard? If wireless, have you replaced the batteries? If you connect a different keyboard, do the symptoms change, remain the same, get worse, better?

@music2myear thanks, I have edited the question accordingly.

Keyboards are pretty cheap. Your next troubleshooting step should be to get a cheap keyboard, or even borrow one if you can. You only need it long enough to confirm whether the problems continue when you use a different keyboard.
